# CF push works nicely, automated deploy fails on Bluemix

Tags: jenkins, ibm-cloud

I have a Java maven project that i deploy to Bluemix using `cf push`. Works like a charm. It has this manifest:

```
    applications:
    - services:
      - Monitoring and Analytics-gm
      - somedb
      disk_quota: 1024M
      hosts:
      - someapp
      name: someapp
      path: target/someapp-0.0.2.war
      domain: mybluemix.net
      instances: 1
      memory: 512M
```

However when I push my repository to hub.jazz.net and kick off build and deploy, the deploy step fails. I checked the artifacts in the build step and the war file got created.

The error message is:
`Server error, status code: 400, error code: 170004, message: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase`

What do I miss?

## Update

### The last lines from the successful build script:

```
    [INFO] Packaging webapp
    [INFO] Assembling webapp [someapp] in [/home/jenkins/workspace/8c791c21-d195-9b03-f3ab-1c2cb5a8a9b4/0d82aa76-8fb2-463b-b1d6-6ec80a763706/target/someapp-0.0.2]
    [INFO] Processing war project
    [INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/jenkins/workspace/8c791c21-d195-9b03-f3ab-1c2cb5a8a9b4/0d82aa76-8fb2-463b-b1d6-6ec80a763706/src/main/webapp]
    [INFO] Webapp assembled in [56 msecs]
    [INFO] Building war: /home/jenkins/workspace/8c791c21-d195-9b03-f3ab-1c2cb5a8a9b4/0d82aa76-8fb2-463b-b1d6-6ec80a763706/target/someapp-0.0.2.war
    [INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 11.424 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-15T10:59:52+00:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 17M/27M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Uploading artifacts ...
    UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL
    Total time: 2 seconds
    Finished: SUCCESS
```

As you can see the `target/someapp-0.0.2.war` is build which is the one referred to in the deploy script

### The last lines from the failed deploy script

```
    cf --version
    /usr/bin/cf-orig/cf version 6.7.0-IDS-2014-12-04T10:56:46+00:00
    + echo 'Target: https://api.ng.bluemix.net'
    Target: https://api.ng.bluemix.net
    + source _deploy.sh
    ++ cf push someapp
    Updating app someapp in org someuser@ibm.com / space somespace as someuser@ibm.com...
    OK
    
    Uploading someapp...
    Uploading app files from: /home/jenkins/workspace/8c791c21-d195-9b03-f3ab-1c2cb5a8a9b4/7c0cd4a8-8ecf-4020-ae82-fc567dd666e9
    Uploading 1.9M, 37 files
    
                                 
    Done uploading
    OK
    
    Stopping app app someapp in org someuser@ibm.com / space somespace as someuser@ibm.com...
    OK
    
    Starting app someapp in org someuser@ibm.com / space somespace as someuser@ibm.com...
    -----> Downloaded app package (3.9M)
    -----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (4.0K)
    
    FAILED
    Server error, status code: 400, error code: 170004, message: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
    
    TIP: use 'cf logs someapp --recent' for more information
    Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

### log from cf logs someapp --recent

```
    2015-09-15T22:53:49.75+0800 [API/5]      OUT Updated app with guid 0ac55e94-12b6-490c-99a9-22dfd96ef293 ({"name"=>"someapp"})
    2015-09-15T22:54:06.06+0800 [API/5]      OUT Updated app with guid 0ac55e94-12b6-490c-99a9-22dfd96ef293 ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
    2015-09-15T22:54:09.68+0800 [DEA/3]      OUT Got staging request for app with id 0ac55e94-12b6-490c-99a9-22dfd96ef293
    2015-09-15T22:54:15.04+0800 [API/6]      OUT Updated app with guid 0ac55e94-12b6-490c-99a9-22dfd96ef293 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
    2015-09-15T22:54:15.22+0800 [STG/3]      OUT -----> Downloaded app package (3.9M)
    2015-09-15T22:54:15.40+0800 [STG/3]      OUT -----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (4.0K)
    2015-09-15T22:54:15.84+0800 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Liberty Buildpack Version: v1.22-20150824-1104
    2015-09-15T22:54:15.84+0800 [STG/0]      ERR E, [2015-09-15T14:54:15.846523 #56] ERROR -- /var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/b1841a6c-5f84-4c40-ac86-9f4d5e8f0643_e788f7b61c5fadd2fec138a1417cd3e1d345df32/lib/liberty_buildpack/buildpack.rb:50:in `rescue in drive_buildpack_with_logger': Compile failed with exception #<RuntimeError: No supported application type was detected>
    2015-09-15T22:54:15.84+0800 [STG/0]      ERR No supported application type was detected
    2015-09-15T22:54:15.85+0800 [STG/0]      OUT Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
    2015-09-15T22:54:16.70+0800 [API/6]      ERR encountered error: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
```

I tried:

- no `path:` in manifest.yml
- `path: target/someapp-0.0.2.war` (that works on local `cf push`)
- `path: someapp-0.0.2.war`

None of them worked

Comment: Stephan, hard to say without more details. I could imagine that the war file cannot be found. Try to remove "target" from the path. If you have two stages (1. compile maven, 2. deploy) then the deploy stage is by default the output directory of the first step.

Comment: The compile works, in the artifact tab of compile the war is listed in the target directory - that's the mystery

Comment: Can you view the deployment log information in hub.jazz.net? You should be able to see the reason for the failure prior to the error message you have posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aaarrgghh..... 5 hours of my life gone.
I deleted the project and recreated it. When checking the **Build Archive Directory** it had the entry `target` (seems to get added when you select mvn). Despite the fact that I tried with `path: someapp-0.0.2.war`, that didn't work.

Only after **removing** `target` and setting `path: target/someapp-0.0.2.war` the now clean project did build.

**So lesson learned**: When switching to a mvn build, remove the  `target` from the **Build Archive Directory**

Answer (score 1):

Yeah usually the error you got means if wasn't able to find the source for your app or the source for the app is wrong...  You could also try adding the following line to `manifest.yml`.

```
buildpack: liberty-for-java
```

Your new manifest would be.

`applications:
- services:
  - Monitoring and Analytics-gm
  - somedb
  disk_quota: 1024M
  hosts:
  - someapp
  name: someapp
  path: target/someapp-0.0.2.war
  buildpack: liberty-for-java
  domain: mybluemix.net
  instances: 1
  memory: 512M`

Comment: Tried that. The funny thing: it works local when I run mvn -B package and cf push. I have another project with a similar setup (short of the actual name it's the same) that works like a charm. The war file is build and I can download it. It's the same as the local created one